# How can I find the frequency of a variable within Lat-Long bounds?

Tags: r

```
all.lat     all.long    all.season
41.69000    -71.56639   JJA
41.69000    -71.56639   MAM
41.69000    -72.56639   MAM
41.69000    -71.56639   MAM
41.69000    -71.56639   JJA
41.69000    -73.56639   MAM
41.69000    -71.56639   SON
41.69000    -73.56639   MAM
41.69000    -71.56639   JJA
41.69000    -74.56639   MAM
42.86250    -71.95972   DJF
42.86250    -75.95972   DJF
42.94806    -71.46389   JJA
42.94806    -71.46389   MAM
42.94806    -71.46389   MAM
42.84250    -71.70722   MAM
42.84250    -71.70722   JJA
42.94806    -75.46389   SON
42.94806    -75.46389   DJF
42.85750    -71.50667   MAM
```

So I'm basically, trying to find the frequency of seasons in a range of Lat-Long.

Basically, I want to mention four Lat-Long values (Max and minimum values) and I want to find a count of each season in this bound.

Intended output (Just an example):

```
DJF = 5
SON = 20
MAM = 50
JJA = 13
```

I know how to find frequency in R, but I'm not sure how to tie it to Lat-Long values.

[image]

Comment: Huh? How is that intended output calculated?

Comment: Oh, I just want to find how many times each season occurred. It need not be in that format ofcourse, All I need is the numbers. The numbers are fictitious for illustration purposes! :) I will make a Pie chart out of these numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data frame is called `df` and your minima/maxima are in `minlat`/`maxlat`/`minlong`/`maxlong`, this should work:

```
sel <- which(all.lat <= maxlat & all.lat >= minlat &
             all.long <= maxlong & all.long >= minlong)
table(df$all.season[sel])
```

Comment: One question, how can I get this into a dataframe format where one column has the Season Name and another column the count. It will be easier to plot in ggplot...Thanks.

Comment: You could put `as.data.frame()` around the result.

Comment: One question, will this clip correctly if the box is not horizontal? What if I have 4 different lat-long coordinates each for the bounds instead of two right now?